# Conditional Notifications

Tags: docusignapi

I have a checkbox list of locations on my powerform and I'd like to implement logic that sends a copy of the signed powerform to the location based on the users selection. Is such conditional logic possible? Would this be something that could be done using the API perhaps?

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario with an example?

Comment: Um, I think I gave the example. I have a powerform. It has a checkbox list. I'd like to send email notifications based on the choice selected within that checkbox list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have DocuSign automatically send the completed/signed document(s) to specific locations. However, you could achieve the same end result by doing the following:

1. Configure [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/custom-connect-configuration.htm) to subscribe to the "Envelope Complete" notification and specify that you want the notification to contain the document(s) as well (in addition to the form data, recipient data, etc. that it contains by default).
2. Design your listener application (where DocuSign Connect will send HTTP notifications each time an Envelope is Completed) to parse the payload of each request received and use the form data to determine where the Completed document(s) need to be sent. Then, programmatically extract the documents from the payload of that request and send them to the correct location(s).

In other words, you create a simple (*listener*) application and configure DocuSign Connect to send an HTTP notification to that application's endpoint each time an Envelope is completed. The body of each notification that your listener application receives from DocuSign Connect will contain info about Envelope Status, Recipients, Form Data, and also the document bytes (provided that you've configured DocuSign Connect to include the documents in the notifications it sends). Your listener app then has all the info it requires in order to send the completed document to the location that the user/signer specified on the form.

Comment: Oh I think I see how this would work. So I'd have an external application doing the actual notification logic and it would be trigged by a sort of webhook (Docusign Connect)?